# If $||f'(x)||\le M \;,\,\forall x\in (a,b)$ then $||f'(x)||\le M \;,\,\forall x\in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

The following proposition is true?

> *Proposition.* Let $f:U\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$  a differentiable function where $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ $\color{blue}{(m\ge 2)}$  open set and $[a,b]\subset U$ an interval.
>
> If $||f'(x)||\le M \;,\,\forall x\in (a,b)$  then $||f'(x)||\le M \;,\,\forall x\in [a,b]$.

If $m=n=1$ holds by Darboux's Theorem.

$(a,b):=\{(1-t)a+tb:0<t<1\}$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your question is wrong(enunciate). What is an interval in $\mathbb{R}^m$??

Comment: @LuisValerin $(a,b):=\{(1-t)a+tb:0<t<1\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $m=2$, $n=1$, try $f(x) = x (1 - e^{-x^2/y^4})$ for $y \ne 0$, $x$ for $y = 0$. This has $\nabla f(0,0) = (1,0)$ but $\nabla f(0,y) = (0,0)$ for $y \ne 0$.  Note that 
$ |x e^{-x^2/y^4}| \le c y^2$ where $c$ is the maximum value of $t e^{-t^2}$, implying that $f$ is differentiable on $y=0$.

Comment: .@RobertIsrael Thanks for your solution, just a question when $m=1$ and $n\ge2$ the proposition is true?